How to create a download files button in ckan?
Hi I am currently using Ckan2.10 and would like to create a Download button in the ckan webpage. After clicked on the Download button, it will call the plugin.py to generate an excel file, but how can I pass the excel file back to the html page so that user is able to download the excel file?
I am trying to upload my excel file (that I have created in the plugin.py) to the api/v3/action/resource_create,
requests.post("http://localhost:5000/api/v3/action/resource_create",
     data = {"package_id": "test1234"},
     headers={"X-CKAN-API-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
     files={"upload", open("the excel path", "rb")}
}

When I execute the above code, ckan will prompt error
NotImplementedError: Streamed bodies and files are mutually exclusive.
I am trying to follow the document, https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/filestore.html, to create the resource and upload the excel file into the resource then user can download from there. Not sure if this works. Appreciate if someone will enlighten me, thank you very much.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

if you want to upload xslx file, you should enable Datapusher and Datastore extensions. That would give you option to download the files out of the box
